# rails link_to generates unwanted id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index for a model "arbete" and if an :id is supplied it filters the index and shows only the index for the vehicle with the id.

if I create a link_to in the view that shows the whole index again it still generates the index link and the id again even though I haven´t supplied an action or an id.

```
link_to("show all", :controller => 'arbete')
```

generates:

```
<a href="/arbete/index/22">show all</a>
```

The only solution I have found is to specify :id => ' ' and then I get the link:`<a href="/arbete/index">`

why is it behaving like this?

**Update**

arbete_controller.rb

```
 def index

     @arbetecl = Arbete.order("id ASC").where(:oppen => false)
     if params[:id].present?
     @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
      @arbeteop = @vehicle.arbetes.all
      else
     @arbeteop = Arbete.order("id ASC").where(:oppen => true)
   end
```

link in view

```
<li><%= link_to "Testarbete", :controller => 'arbete' %></li>
```

generates if the id params is sent.

```
<li><a href="/arbete/index/67">Testarbete</a></li>
```

routes.rb

```
 match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Im thinking its a desired behaviour but I cant find why and it only happens on this model and controller but its also the only one that gets params to its index action.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify both action and controller or write full url helper for which you want to generate link.

```
link_to("show all", {:controller => 'arbete', :action => 'index'})
```

or

```
link_to("show all", arbetes_path)
```

Comment: That still generates an index with and id. The only way it works is by adding :id => ''. This  is strange cause I have never seen this behavior until I tried this filtering tecnique.

Comment: It is really strange. Would you like to share more code so i can review or able to reproduce on my side?